# Add legend for gender/experience in 2016 survey

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey, survey-2016

It is hard to tell which color is for men or women. Can a legend be added to make the data clearer? The summary says that women are less experienced, but tides change halfway through the graph (after 5 years)

[image: genderXexperience]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Welp, we were just teasing.  The survey **is not** quite ready for public consumption and that shouldn't have been available...yet.

We're still working through the data and hope to have it available for viewing next week.

Comment: Thank you. I posted 2 other issues with the survey on here. I found the link from HN.

Comment: @onebree Thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: @bluefeet  I posted the link to reddit. Thought it was official from the URL. Sorry!

Comment: Welp? Do you mean "Well"?

Comment: @PythonMaster: [Probably not, no](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Welp&defid=5929265).

Comment: I'm not sure 'gender' and 'experience' should be juxtaposed (what kind of experience are we talking about?). You can simply call it 'experience' and add the legend.

Comment: @DeerHunter considering the survey wasn't ready when this was seen I might suggest waiting until the correct version is released.